# Concatencation+collecting of ranges in Julia

Tags: julia

According to [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/arrays/#Concatenation-1), `[A; B; C; ...]` calls `vcat()`. So, to concatenate and collect a comprehension of ranges this way

```
>>[1:4; 6:9; 20:23]

12-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
  4
  6
  7
  8
  9
 20
 21
 22
 23
```

I tried to use `vcat()`, but it does not do collecting

```
vcat([i:i+3 for i in [1,6,20]])

3-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 1:4  
 6:9  
 20:23
```

Is there a simple way to collect all values from a comprehension of ranges?

Comment: add `...` as in `vcat([i:i+3 for i in [1,6,20]]...)`

Comment: Moving comment to answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `...` to get

```
julia> vcat([i:i+3 for i in [1,6,20]]...)
12-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
  4
  6
  7
  8
  9
 20
 21
 22
 23
```